# Save file as - dialog box with dynamic data

Tags: jsp

I know that this question is quite common, but its specifics are stumping me.

I have an "export" button which I want to take a load of data generated, create a CSV file, then pop up a Save File As dialog box, to save that file on their local machine.

The name of this file is dynamic, also.

I know how to make the CSV file, but how do I then pop up a box on the client side to let the user download it?

I am using JSP with Struts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to send a response containing your generated csv with a header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your_file.csv
```

Comment: I am putting the filename in as a complete path (/home/joeblogs/blah.csv) and it pops up to save the current JSP page I am on??

Comment: No, this header specifies how browser needs to treat the data it receives. So you need to type a name that will appear in `Save As...` dialog. For example `mydata.csv` or something.